# Executing batch T-SQL Scripts containing GO statements throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to execute SQl Scripts cotaining GO Statements with following code

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(RConnString);
ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
Server server = new Server(svrConnection);
returnvalue = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(strSpScript);
return Convert.ToString(returnvalue);
```

But it throws following excetpion on live. this code works fine in my local pc

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetStatements(String
>   query, ExecutionTypes executionType, Int32& statementsToReverse) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand)

Comment: what's your sql code ?

Comment: there is a sql script of sp with go statements in sql code

Comment: `GO` is a command that *client* tools are meant to use to know to split the script into separate batches and send the batches to SQL Server individually. You're acting in the role of a client tool now so it's up to *your* code to perform that same task - find the `GO`s (being careful around quoted and commented text) - and execute each batch separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like the following:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(RConnString)) 
{
    connection.Open();
    foreach (var batch in strSpScript.Split(new string[] {"\nGO", "\ngo"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
         try
         {
             new SqlCommand(batch, connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
             throw;
         }
    }
}
```

This will only work if you have 'GO' on a newline (and in consistent case) - modify as necessary.

Comment: To be consistent with the other client tools, you would need to also *avoid* splitting the code when `GO` exists within a multi-line comment or a multi-line string literal

Comment: as i have to split Sps and execute in loop, for more secure i can use some unique code in new line like 'GO##' and split with it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - yes, it's not good general purpose code, but if you want something quick & dirty that doesn't involve writing a parser, and you control the input, this will do the job.

Comment: @Sagar yes, this will work, but the advantage of using GO is that your scripts are then portable across different clients, so for example you can open your script in Management Studio for debugging.

Answer (score 6):

`GO` **does not exist** in T-SQL. It is a feature of tools like SQL Server Management Studio, not the language itself. Instead, you should locate any `GO`, and **split the command there**, executing them separately. Alternatively, refactor your T-SQL to work without `GO` - in many cases, `EXEC` can help here.